# PyQt QChart Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, диаграммы

Здравствуйте!
Переписал пример barchart из Qt на PyQt. Все прекрасно работает.
Вот код (может быть кому-нибудь будет интересно)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QBarSeries, QBarSet, QLegend, QBarCategoryAxis
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter

class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        set0 = QBarSet("Джейн")
        set1 = QBarSet("Джон")
        set2 = QBarSet("Александр")
        set3 = QBarSet("Мария")
        set4 = QBarSet("Саманта")
        for a in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:     # это данные для Джейн. В январе 1, в феврале 2, ...
            set0.append(a)
        for a in [5,2,3,4,5,6]:     # это данные для Джон. В январе 5, в феврале 2, ...
            set1.append(a)        
        for a in [1,5,3,4,5,6]:
            set2.append(a)     
        for a in [1,2,5,4,5,6]:
            set3.append(a)   
        for a in [1,2,3,5,5,6]:
            set4.append(a)
        series = QBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.append(set3)
        series.append(set4)
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Пример столбчатой диаграммы")
        #chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.AllAnimations)
        categories = ["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь"]
        axis = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis.append(categories)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAxisX(axis, series)
        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Столбчатая диаграмма")
    window.resize(500, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Далее переписал пример piechart. А вот он не работает.
Вываливается с ошибкой:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(program exited with code: 139)
Похоже, что вываливается на строке chart = QChart()
Вот код примера (не обращайте внимания на лишний import).

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore    import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRect)

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QStyledItemDelegate, QApplication, QMainWindow, QSplashScreen, 
                             qApp, QTabWidget, QMessageBox, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
                             QTableView, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QDateEdit, 
                             QCalendarWidget, QLabel, QComboBox)

from PyQt5.QtSql     import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlRelation, QSqlRelationalDelegate,
                             QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery)

from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QPixmap, QIcon, QPen
from PyQt5.QtChart   import (QChart, QChartView, QBarSeries, QPieSeries,QPieSlice,
                             QBarSet, QLegend, QBarCategoryAxis)

class TestWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    series = QPieSeries()
    series.append("Jane", 1)
    series.append("Joe", 2)
    series.append("Andy", 3)
    series.append("Barbara", 4)
    series.append("Axel", 5)

    slice = series.slices()[1]
    slice.setExploded()
    slice.setLabelVisible()
    slice.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGreen, 2))
    slice.setBrush(Qt.green)  

    chart = QChart()        !!!!!!похоже здесь вываливается
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.setTitle("Simple piechart example")
    chart.legend().hide()

    chartView = QChartView(chart)
    chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)   

    self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    #window.setWindowTitle("Пирог")
    window.resize(500, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Обрати внимание, что весь код инициализации QChart-а расположен не в конструкторе, а в классе.

Соответственно выполняется он ещё до инициализации QApplication, что и приводит к сегфолту.

Comment: Вряд ли в этом дело, т.к. инициализация `QChart` происходит в конструкторе класса виджета, который инициализируется после создания `QApplicaton`

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на код. Отступы настройки QChart-а такие же как отступ сигнатуры конструктора.

Comment: Возможно вы правы (сейчас не могу его код проверить). Тогда, если вы проверили на ошибку сделав правильные отступы, предлагаю исправленный код в ответ поместить (я бы попутно его отформатировал, а то столько лишнего... :))

Comment: Вы правы, дело было в отступах и ошибка происходила на строке `chart = QChart()`

Comment: Большое всем спасибо! Дело действительно в отступах (детская ошибка)

Answer (score 0):

Кое-что исправил в коде:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtChart import (QChart, QChartView, QBarSeries, QPieSeries, QPieSlice,
                           QBarSet, QLegend, QBarCategoryAxis)


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        series = QPieSeries()
        series.append("Jane", 1)
        series.append("Joe", 2)
        series.append("Andy", 3)
        series.append("Barbara", 4)
        series.append("Axel", 5)

        slice = series.slices()[1]
        slice.setExploded()
        slice.setLabelVisible()
        slice.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGreen, 2))
        slice.setBrush(Qt.green)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Simple piechart example")
        chart.legend().hide()

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.resize(500, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]